# Field not being written to in helper class

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, update

I am trying to schedule a batch job, take the Id of said batch job and then write it to a field on the triggering record.The scheduling works successfully, it just doesn't write to the record.

Trigger Handler Code

```
public class FOTriggerHandler {

   public override void beforeUpdate() {

   Map<Id, FO> fundOppsMap = new Map<Id, FO>();

   for(sObject sObj : Trigger.newMap.values()) {

     FO oldFundOpp = (FO)Trigger.oldMap.get(sObj.Id);
     FO newFundOpp = (FO)sObj;

    if(logic) {
      fundOppsMap.put(newFundOpp.Id,newfundOpp);
    }
  }
  if(!fundOppsMap.keySet().isEmpty()) {
     FOTriggerHelper.scheduleBatch(fundOppsMap);
  }
 }
}
```

Helper Code

```
public with sharing class FOTriggerHelper {


  public static void scheduleBatch(Map<Id, FO> fundingOppsMap) {
  
     for(FO fundOpp : [SELECT Id, batchId__c FROM FO WHERE Id IN: fundOppsMap.keySet()] {
         String schedBatchId = System.scheduleBatch(new Batch(fundOpp.Id), 'Batch', 60);
         fundOpp.batchId__c = schedBatchId;
  }
 }
}
```

Can't seem to figure out why the batchId__c field isn't being written to in the UI. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the field on the records in `Trigger.new`, not query them. Doing the latter means you have a second version of these records in memory which never actually get committed to the database.

You are passing in the `Trigger.new` records of interest already in the map, so:

```
public static void scheduleBatch(Map<Id, FundingOpportunity> fundingOppsMap) {
    for (FundingOpportunity fundOpp : fundingOppsMap.values()) {
        String schedBatchId = System.scheduleBatch(new Batch(fundOpp.Id), 'Batch', 60);

        fundOpp.batchId__c = schedBatchId;
    }
}
```

That said, be aware that you may run out of [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) in terms of number of async you can set up per transaction - as soon as you have more than 100 things will break. You might like to consider an approach like those covered in [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) which is supported by two code examples ([here](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) and [here](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-from-trigger)).

PS: Also note that:

1. Your trigger declaration is syntactically incorrect (you cannot use "beforeUpdate" to define the event).
2. If you are simply iterating `Trigger.newMap.values()` you might as well iterate `Trigger.new`.
3. The `Trigger.new/newMap/old/oldMap` lists and maps are strongly typed with the type for the contextual trigger, so you do not need to do all the type casting you're doing.